# How dynamically add new input element if all others was filled in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

please watch this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MsvvP47tUAyBlQsAYW3Y?p=preview)

So I working with angular and need to add new input field when all others are filled in (by default on page placed 5 inputs and if all of them are filled automatically add one more input if new input also using will add one more input and etc).

For generate inputs I use ng-repeat and name_list[] for it:

```
<div collect-input>
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="(i, name) in name_list track by $index">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="data.name_list[i]" add-input/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each input have directive attr "add-input" with $watch() method inside. This method method track when $isEmpty parameter had changed.
Then value function pass value of this parameter to listen function.

```
directive('addInput', ['$compile', '$sce', '$timeout', function ($compile, $sce, $timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: ['^collectInput', '?ngModel'],

    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
       var collectInput = ctrl[0];
       var ngModel = ctrl[1];

       $timeout(function(){ 
           scope.$watch(
               function(){  
                     return ngModel.$isEmpty(ngModel.$modelValue);
               },

               function(isEmpty){
                   collectInput.reportInput(ngModel, isEmpty);
               }
           );
       },1000)
    }
}
```

}]);

Then this function call "reportInput()" that placed inside parent directive "collect-input". Main goal of this function is to add new input name to name_list[] for generating via ng-repeat

```
userApp.directive('collectInput', function() {
  return {
  restrict: 'A',
  controller: function($scope) {
    var dirtyCount = 0;
    this.reportInput = function(modelValue, isEmpty) {
      var count = $scope.name_list.length;        

       if (isEmpty == false){
           dirtyCount ++;
           console.log('+1:' + dirtyCount);
       }

       if (isEmpty == true){
           if (dirtyCount <= 0){
                dirtyCount = 0;
               console.log('0:' + dirtyCount);
           }
           else if(dirtyCount > 0){
               dirtyCount --;
               console.log('-1:' + dirtyCount)
           }
       }


       if (count === dirtyCount) {
             $scope.name_list.push(modelValue);
             //dirtyCount = dirtyCount + 1;
       }


      console.log('count:' + count);
      console.log('dirtyCount:' + dirtyCount);
      console.log(modelValue)
    }
  },
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

  }}});
```

So when I filled 5 default inputs everything is good after it appears new input but it is all in my IDE it work perfect if I add only one symbol for 5+ label (in plunker in some reason it not work) but when I add or delete something more code logic crash. It's hard to explain. I hope Plunker code more clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, and could be optimized, but here's my idea:

HTML :

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="name in name_list">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input class="form-control" ng-model="name"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
//watch any modification in the list of names
$scope.$watchCollection('data.name_list', function (list) {
    //is there an empty name in the list?
    if (!list.filter(function (name) { return !name; }).length) {
        //if not, let's add one.
        data.name_list.push('');
        //and that will automatically add an input to the html
    }
});
```

I don't see the point of a directive.

Comment: Well, thank you for idea, I used it in my app, but I use $watch with true argument, because i need not only track changes in array but I need to know when will change value of array items